# Is this C# struct guaranteed to have the desired size?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I would like to create a type safe pointer structure by wrapping an `IntPtr`:

```
struct Pointer<T>
{
    private IntPtr ptr;

    // methods marshalling from and to T
}
```

But I also want to be able to marshal `Pointer<T>` instances as if they were `IntPtr`s, so they need to have the same size and layout. Is that guaranteed?

If not, is it if I add

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
```

at the top?

Basically, at the end I should be able to marshal this C struct

```
struct Foo {
    int *data;
};
```

using this C# struct:

```
struct Foo
{
    public Pointer<int> data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is already fine as-is, no need to help.

A struct type in C# automatically gets a [StructLayout] attribute.  The default is Sequential with a packing of 8.  Which is the same kind of packing used by default in unmanaged code.  It doesn't matter anyway when you have only one field in the struct.

Just make sure you don't add any fields and don't use automatic properties.  You can double-check with Marshal.SizeOf(), it should be 4 in 32-bit mode and 8 in 64-bit mode.  Or in other words, equal to IntPtr.Size

Comment: What if the a `Pointer<T>` is a member of another struct. Will it take the same space as an `IntPtr` and will the members behind it be aligned the same?

Comment: That entirely depends on the declaration of *that* structure.

Comment: let's say it has `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]`

Comment: Don't make it arbitrary.  Using a packing of 1 is very unusual, you'd only ever see it used in code that writes data to a stream.  Or broken code of course :)  A stream would never contain a pointer value.  If you don't know the packing then *always* guess at 8.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)] will only affect the alignment of variables in the struct, not the size of the variables it self. They still are 32bit/64bit.